# .apk does not exist error when exporting Android project in Eclipse using android-sdk_r06-mac_86

Tags: eclipse, android

I get a .apk does not exist error  when exporting Android project in Eclipse using android-sdk_r06-mac_86.

I never got the error in the previous version of the SDK.
Off course the .apk file doesn't exist. I'm trying to build and sign it.

How do I fix this problem?
I prefer to getting it to work in Eclipse again.

---

Here are some more details about the problem.

I am running Eclipse on a Mac.
Everything was ok, until I updated the SDK version (and ADT plugin) to
the sdk 2.2.

Now I can't use the emulator, or export .apk files for most of my pre Android-sdk-2.2 projects.

The error message contains something like: ".apk file not found".
When looking in the projects bin directory the .apk file isn't there.
How did that happen. I didn't delete them.

When I use the "android update project" on the command line I can generate a build.xml file.

However when I use ant debug to export or build the .apk file I get the following error message:

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/apps/android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-4/ant/ant_rules_r2.xml:220: null returned: 139

I have also tried to use the project clean option in Eclipse.

It looks like countless hours of work have been wasted.

Since I can't build the .apk file I can't move it to the emulator, or phone.
This wasn't a problem in the previous Android-SDK version.

Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Its better you install .apk files via command line method. like
Launch the emulator
cd to location of emulator launcher/tools/#adb install location/application.apk
or just read these 
[Install](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator) | |
[Uninstall](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-uninstall-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator)